# SwiftUI how to combine From Section with LazyVGrid?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let say I have a table of texts with different lengths

```swift
let data = [("aaa","bbb","ccc"),("aaaaaaa","bb","ccccc"),("a","bbbbbb","cc"),("aaaa","bbbbbb","c")]
```

I can organize them into a LazyVGrid for nice alignment

```swift
        LazyVGrid(columns: [
            GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading),
            GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading),
            GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading)
        ]){
            ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self){ i in
                let datum = data[i]
                Text(datum.0)
                Text(datum.1)
                Text(datum.2)
            }
        }
```

[image]

Now I want to put it into a Form Section, but the section treats the LazyVGrid as a single item so there are no separators between rows:

```swift
        Form{
            Section{
                LazyVGrid(columns: [
                    GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading),
                    GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading),
                    GridItem(.flexible(),alignment: .leading)
                ]){
                    ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self){ i in
                        let datum = data[i]
                        Text(datum.0)
                        Text(datum.1)
                        Text(datum.2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

If I remove the LazyVGrid, I get the separators but now have no column aligment

```swift
        Form{
            Section{
                ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self){ i in
                    let datum = data[i]
                    HStack
                    {
                        Text(datum.0)
                        Text(datum.1)
                        Text(datum.2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

How do I get both the row separator effect and the column alignment effect at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame(maxWidth:)` modifier can be a helpful solution. This modifier sets a maximum width for the view and allows it to adjust its size within that constraint. It's worth noting that the view will only be sized to its natural size if it's smaller than the maximum width specified. If the view's natural size is larger than the maximum width, it will be shrunk down to fit.

To ensure the view is aligned as desired, consider using alignment to set leading alignment.

```
Form{
  Section{
    ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self){ i in
        let datum = data[i]
        HStack
        {
            Text(datum.0)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, 
                       alignment: .leading)
            
            Text(datum.1)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, 
                       alignment: .leading)
            Text(datum.2)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, 
                       alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]